# connect to mySQL using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

Im using xampp control on macbook and trying to connect to 'localhost/phpmyadmin'. I have apache and mySQL both running but im getting an error

```
#1 - Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/kb/6g_npz7s1511w39k7v224gq80000gn/T/#sql4e6_1_2.MYI' (Errcode: 13)
```

Any ideas about what this might be or how i could connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you'd get that error because the directory that MySQL is using to write temp files to isn't writeable by the mysql user; usually that directory would be `/var/tmp` or something similar. Try starting mysql with the `--tmp-dir=/var/tmp` and see if it still complains. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir

Answer (score 0):

check the port of the apache .... by selecting checkport ... and in the browser set the url as: localhost:(port number)/phpmyadmin